# How to properly use a lock

Tags: c#, locking

I would like to know how to lock a boolean, which from what i can read requires another "object" to be created and used for the locking mechanism... my problem is that i don't understand how this piece of code:

```
lock (this.mLock) { this.end5 = true; }
```

will actually do anything at all if at the same time, somewhere else within the code/in another method, i am making a read on that variable (end5) within an if statement?

```
if(this.end5==true)
    DO SOMETHING;
```

if someone could explain this to me if i'm wrong i'd be grateful, but won't the "Read" within the IF not care in the slightest that mLock is locked and therefore the "Read" could occur while End5 is being set and thus serves no purpose at all?? and if that's the case, how do i ensure that the "Read" waits until end5 is "Released" before reading it?

Sorry if i'm just confused... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not wrong.

`lock` constrains access to a critical section. In your example you made the setting of `end5` be a critical section... but not the reading of it. So the lock is not helpful for what you're asking. You'd want to check the lock on the reading side as well.

But you've got to be careful about how you define your critical sections. If you need to guarantee that the value of `end5` remains unchanged throughout DO SOMETHING, then it needs to be inside another critical section. Just make sure not to cause any deadlocks :)

Comment: It's not worthless.  It's actually quite important.  Without the critical section the runtime can perform all sorts of optimizations that would result in the program not functioning, such as caching the value and never inspecting the result written in another thread.

Comment: How is it important? If they're reading (and potentially writing) it "unlocked" in other places because that's the only place they've put the lock, then its useless. And since the user is concerned about the reads and DO SOMETHING, then I hold that my statement ("mostly" worthless) is true - it does nothing to help with reads.

Comment: No, it's not useless.  It introduces memory barriers in such a way as to ensure that the reads are actually reading what you think that they're reading.  All sorts of assumptions that you think you have about programs fall flat when you start working with multithreaded programming, like the fact that a value written in one place will actually be read in another.

Comment: @Servy - having lock on write indeed have non-trivial impact on that piece of code, but it is unlikely OP (or almost anyone else) can reason about what that impact really is. I think "mostly worthless" is very good way of describing "it does something that most people will not understand and may or may not be necessary. Whoever wrote the code may or may not know the impact and possibly did not plan it to be written that way".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's not mostly worthless.  It's vitally important.  The code won't function properly without it.  Stale cached values can continue to be used from the reading thread *indefinitely* instead of reading the newly written values.  That's not "mostly worthless".  That's **essential to the function of the code**.  Locking only works when you *always do so when accessing that shared state*.  Locks are *entirely pointless* if you don't use them *everywhere*.  If you won't lock when reading, then you may as well not lock when writing.  Both changes have the same effect.

Comment: "Locking only works when you always do so when accessing that shared state. Locks are entirely pointless if you don't use them everywhere." I think that's what I was saying. The lock around the write is entirely pointless ("mostly worthless") by itself (as presented in the OP's question). You need the corresponding lock around the read for it to have any point (worth).

Comment: the way he explained it makes a lot of sense... while i do understand what @Servy is saying, that was not really my concern here. I wanted to know if it had an impact on my read, which it doesn't in this scenario. I would ultimately want to make sure, when i read it, that it is not being updated at the same time, and the Critical sections does that, if i use them correctly. Thanks all!

Comment: @Servy - My comment was to "lock only on write is mostly worthless" (as shown in original sample), which does not seem to be what you are talking about "always do so when accessing that shared state". I'm sorry my comment was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your unlocked read does not care about the lock. Lock while reading. It could look like this:

```
bool result;
lock (mLock)
    result = end5;

if (result)
    DoSomething();
```

That said, you might want to extend the locked region to cover the branch and `DoSomething`. Depends on what you want code to make atomic.